# Convert word to number and vice versa using same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a function using Python to convert a number to its equivalent word and vice versa.

One function is done, confusion is about the second. For this, I can use two dictionaries, in which the key and value pair are interchanged, but I was wondering if I could use a single dictionary for both of the functions?

I tried in a way, but my answer is not in sync with the list order. If there is a way to get the list in the mentioned order then please let me know.

Here's my code:

```
nDict={"one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4,"five":5,"six":6,"seven":7,"eight":8,"nine":9,"ten":10}
global nDict

def numberToWord(answer):    
    myAnsList=list(answer)  
    print(myAnsList)  
    myAnsWordList=[]  
    for k,i in nDict.items():    
        if str(i) in myAnsList:    
            myAnsWordList.append(k)  
    myAnsString=' '.join(myAnsWordList)  
    print(myAnsString)

numberToWord('824')
```

Current output:

```
['8', '2', '4']
two four eight
```

Desired output:

```
['8', '2', '4']
eight two four
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
nDict={"0":"zero","1":"one","2":"two","3":"three","4":"four","5":"five","6":"six","7":"seven","8":"eight","9":"nine"}

def printNumbers(numbers):
    print(list(numbers))
    print(' '.join(map(nDict.get, numbers)))
```

If you change the order of your dictionary then you can use the character as the key to the word instead of visa versa.

Update to use the same dictionary
Note, 10 is composed of 2 characters so it won't be exactly the same - instead of 10 you will have one zero

```
nDict={"zero":"0", "one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4,"five":5,"six":6,"seven":7,"eight":8,"nine":9}

def integerToString(answer):    
    myAnsList=list(answer)  
    print(myAnsList)  
    myAnsWordList=[]  
    for num in myAnsList:
        for k,i in nDict.items():
            if str(i) == num:
                myAnsWordList.append(k)  
    myAnsString=' '.join(myAnsWordList)  
    print(myAnsString)

integerToString('824')
```

Update 2:

Based on comments, the dictionary can be reversed and speed up the conversion

```
nDict={"zero":"0", "one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4,"five":5,"six":6,"seven":7,"eight":8,"nine":9}
revNDict = { str(v): k for k, v in nDict.items() }

def printNumbers(numbers):
    print(list(numbers))
    print(' '.join(map(revNDict.get, numbers)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, but my question is. can i use the same single dictionary which i have given in question for both functions i.e for "string to integer" and "integer to string"

Comment: Not entirely sure why you'd want to do this but yes you can, it will be less efficient though.

Comment: you can easily get a reverse mapping with `dict((val,key) for key,val in original_dict.items())`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Nice! That builds the dict in my original response, I'll update with a hybrid response for the speed boost.

Comment: Perfect suggestion Joran. Thank you, it will be much useful for lengthy dictionary mappings.